# good online source or book to understand prototype properties of javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class with javascript and I come across with prototype.

I tried to google it and still I don't seems to understand it well.

Anyone have read any nice online source or books that talk about it?

Comment: [Stevey's Blog Rants: The Universal Design Pattern](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype) (online)
- [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) (book)
- [JavaScript Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767) (book)

Comment: JavaScript Garden  seems awesome , thanks!

Answer (score 2):

googled it, found some good articles:

http://particletree.com/features/javascript-basics-for-prototyping

http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/10/23/prototyping-with-javascript

http://www.southsearepublic.org/article/1174/read/object_oriented_javascript__prototyping

Comment: However, how can you tell they are all *good* in 1:37 mins?

Comment: seems awesome , looking into it

Comment: @Casper, I haven't just pasted the first 3 results ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many good javascript books. I would suggest,

1. Pro Javascript Techniques - John Resig
2. Javascript: The Good Parts - Douglas Crockford

And as for online sources, there is none better and comprehensive than [Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Here is the section on [object.prototype by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Answer (score 0):

*The Good parts* by Douglas Crockford and *JavaScript patterns* by Stoyan Stevanov